# Peewee PaginatedQuery.get_page() returns 1 even though page_var has been set explicitly

Tags: python, peewee

Code

```
posts = PaginatedQuery(models.Post.select().order_by(models.Post.pub_date.desc()), 5, page_var=3)
    print(posts.page_var)
    print(posts.get_page())
```

This will print 3 and 1. How do I get `get_page()` to return the page that has been set at `page_var`?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the page_var variable.

if you look at the code in playhouse.flask_utils you'll see the following

```
def get_page(self):
    curr_page = request.args.get(self.page_var)
    if curr_page and curr_page.isdigit():
        return max(1, int(curr_page))
    return 1
```

so `page_var` will look at the variable ?3= in the url and `get_page()` will return that value instead of returning the value you give `page_var`